# How to read stdio data with None encoding in Python3?

Tags: python, encoding, subprocess, pipe, stdio

I am trying to read data from a Python script via stdio on my Mac (sharing because I read OS makes difference). I tried reading the incoming stream by

```
sys.stdin.read(NUM_BYTES)
```

and

```
input()
```

for both I get error like

```
 File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

I checked the encoding type in the script sending data and it shows 'None' since it was not set.

So **how to read data which is sent without any encoding?** without changing enconding in sender script.

Answer (score 1):

If you read it as a string, you are using an encoding (whether one was specified at write time or not).

`sys.stdin.buffer.read()` reads STDIN as binary. The `sys.stdin.buffer` is a [`io.BufferedReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader).

Comment: Thank you I am able to read data. If I want to read continuously, can I put it in loop? Or it requires some handling?

Comment: You can put it in a loop if that is what you wish to do. I don't understand what you mean by "requires some handling".

Comment: I kept it in a loop but both sender and receiver were getting stuck at read. After adding flush command it works fine in loop. I meant do I need to flush or not if it is in loop.

Comment: This is very hard to answer if I can't see what you are doing. Also, it is almost certainly not related to this question, so if you still need an answer, you should ask a new question about it; the question about encoding and `read` is answered.